# Collide function - AttributeError: type object 'head' has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently designing a snake game but am having difficulty detecting collisions between sprites and keep on getting the error -AttributeError: type object 'head' has no attribute 'rect'.

I am using the

```
eat = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(head, apple)
```

function to detect collisions.

here is my full code

```
import pygame
import random
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 250, 0)
RED = (250, 0, 0)
Width = 15
Space = 3
Xspeed = 18
Yspeed = 0
Factor = 18
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
segments = 10
class head(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, colour = GREEN):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([Width, Width])
        self.image.fill(colour)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class apple(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, z, q):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([Width, Width])
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = z
        self.rect.y = q


for i in range(0,20):
    z = random.randint(1,800)
    q = random.randint(1,800)
    c = apple(z,q)



pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 800])

pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')

allspriteslist = pygame.sprite.Group()


SnakeSegments = []
for i in range(segments):
    x = 250 - (Width + Space) * i
    y = 30
    h = head(x, y)
    SnakeSegments.append(h)
    allspriteslist.add(h)

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if Xspeed == -Factor:
                    Xspeed = 0
                if Xspeed == Factor:
                    Xspeed = Factor
                else:
                    Xspeed = Xspeed - Factor
                    Yspeed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if Xspeed == Factor:
                    Xspeed = 0
                if Xspeed == -Factor:
                    Xspeed = -Factor
                else:
                    Xspeed = Xspeed + Factor
                    Yspeed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if Yspeed == -Factor:
                    Yspeed = 0
                if Yspeed == Factor:
                    Yspeed = Factor
                else:
                    Yspeed = Yspeed - Factor
                    Xspeed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if Yspeed == Factor:
                    Yspeed = 0
                if Yspeed == -Factor:
                    Yspeed = -Factor
                else:
                    Yspeed = Yspeed + Factor
                    Xspeed = 0
    clock.tick(10)
    OldSegment = SnakeSegments.pop()
    allspriteslist.remove(OldSegment)
    x = SnakeSegments[0].rect.x + Xspeed
    y = SnakeSegments[0].rect.y + Yspeed
    h = head(x, y)
    SnakeSegments.insert(0, h)
    allspriteslist.add(h,c)
    allspriteslist.update()
    print(x,y)
    print(z,q)
    eat = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(head, apple)





    screen.fill(BLACK)
    #game walls
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [0, 0, 800, 10])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [0, 0, 10, 800])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [0, 790, 800, 10])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [790, 0, 10, 800])
    if x <= 10:
        done = True
    if x >= 785:
        done = True
    if y <= 10:
        done = True
    if y >= 785:
        done = True
    allspriteslist.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You are passing the object head into the collide function instead of the instance h. eat = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(head, apple) should be eat = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(h, c). Also, declare c before the for loop so it exists outside of it: c = apple(z,q).

Comment: Thanks it works great now however I cannot declare c before the for loop because then z and q are not defined

Comment: Actually sorry, the variable does exist even if it's created in the for loop. Just a side note, capitalize your class names so they stand out as classes. And use more descriptive names for your variables so you don't confuse yourself when your program gets larger. Give this a read: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Thanks this is a big help however I still get an error message saying z and q are not defined if i state c = apple(z,q) before the for loop

Comment: It's because z & q do not exist outside the apple init function.  self.rect.x = z
        self.rect.y = q